# ggplot and loops

Tags: data-visualization, ggplot2

I have a data file with a lot of different variables. I can plot every variable independently this way:

```
plot_1 <- ggplot(Dataset, aes(x=variable1)) + geom_density()
plot_2 <- ggplot(Dataset, aes(x=variable2)) + geom_density()
plot_3 <- ggplot(Dataset, aes(x=variable3)) + geom_density()
plot_4 <- ggplot(Dataset, aes(x=variable4)) + geom_density()
grid.arrange(plot_1, plot_2, plot_3, plot_4, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

However, I'd like to use a loop function. Is it best to create a vector out of the variables and make something like this?

```
for (i in 1:length(names)) {
   plot_[i] <- ggplot(Dataset, eas(x=names[i])) + geom_density()
}
```

I know this code doesn't work, but at least it shows where I want to head at.

Additionally, how can I create a nice (loop) function that also plots all the plots?

Comment: This type of question really belongs on SO but for that site you really need your sample code to be reproducible (readers don't have access to your "Dataset")

Comment: this may be useful - http://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot2-graphics-in-a-loop/

Answer (score 8):

Create a list to hold your plots

```
plots <- list()
```

Then use `aes_string` instead of `aes`

```
for(nm in names(Dataset)) {
    plots[[nm]] <- ggplot(Dataset, aes_string(x=nm)) + geom_density()
}
```

Here's a full working example you can run

```
set.seed(154)
D <- data.frame(
    x1 = runif(100),
    x2 = rnorm(100)
)

library(ggplot2)
plots <- list()
for(nm in names(D)) {
    plots[[nm]] <- ggplot(data=D) + geom_density(aes_string(x=nm))
}

print(plots[["x1"]])
print(plots[["x2"]])
```

I think passing the `aes` to the `geom` is clearer, but it should work either way.

Comment: `aes_string` instead of `aes` solved my problem, for I had a char vector of column names to run the loop.